# Sorting XML While Converting it to JsonString

Tags: c#, xml, sorting, json.net

Here is sample of XML I have its unsorted

```
<hierarchy>
<date>2015/02/27 16:37:10</date> 
   <folder name="Root" id="Root">
        <file id="Erstg_20.xlsx" /> 
        <file id="AAERG_20.xlsx" />
      <folder name="Xmdg" id="Xmdg">
        <file id="DatePicker_20.xlsx" /> 
        <file id="Abcd_20.xlsx" />
   </folder>
   <folder name="Axcd" id="Axcd">
        <file id="Zfcd_20.xlsx" />
        <file id="Abcd_20.xlsx" />
   </folder>
</folder>
</hierarchy>
```

I want to sort it in a way that all folders in Root node should be sorted in ascending order and files within every node should be sorted in ascending order according to their Id's

Here is how i am doing it right now

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(xmlFilePath);
try {

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
    string rJson = json.Replace("@id", "id");
    json = rJson.Replace("@name", "name");
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(HierarchyJSFilePath, "var jsonStr= " + json + ";");

}
```

Comment: You'll need to sort the xml. Quite ugly because your xml seems to be recursive (there can be files inside folders inside folders inside folders). Inside a single folder, what ordering do you want between files and folders? All the files first (ordered by id), all the folders first (ordered by id), files and  folders mixed and ordered by id

Comment: Yes it is recursive.. The Root Folder Will always be there with same name and ID so first I want to sorts files by their ID in root folder then folders within folders and files with in those folders.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are use SerializeXmlNode instead of using an intermediary object to store the deserialized content, sort it using LINQ and then converting this structure to Json?

Answer (score 1):

You need for example to serialize a Dictionary into json.

You use as keys an Folders (you have to code this) class, and as values a List of Files (you also have to code this). You can easily sort Lists and Dictionaries (don't forget to code the compareTo methods).

Answer (score 0):

If XSLT is an option, you might want to use the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<!-- default : copy everything as is -->
<xsl:template match='node()  |  @*'>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*  |  node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- for elements hierarchy and folder : -->
<!-- sort these before copying -->
<xsl:template match="hierarchy | folder">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*  |  *">
            <xsl:sort select="@id"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

you'd then use the above XSLT Stylesheet (e.g. "C:\Temp\SortAndCopy.xslt") like so:

```
        // load XML file
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(xmlFilePath);
        // load XSLT file
        var transformation = new XslCompiledTransform();
        transformation.Load(@"C:\Temp\SortAndCopy.xslt");
        // perform transformation with XMLWriter
        // writing to new XML document
        XmlDocument sortedXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        using (XmlWriter xw = sortedXmlDoc.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
        {
          transformation.Transform(doc, null, xw);
          xw.Close();
        }
        // further process sortedXmlDoc ...
```